# SQL limit in many join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a big query with a lot of inner join inside in a page on my website.
I want to apply for some left outer join limit 1 but if I put it into the sql give me errors.

This is a small part of my query isn't total, this query is only a part and ISN'T FINISH:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN  (origins 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  origin_aliases ON origin_aliases.origin_id = origins.id 
                        AND origin_aliases.language = '$lang'
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (diets LEFT OUTER JOIN  diet_aliases ON diet_aliases.diet_id = diets.id AND diet_aliases.language = '$lang') 
                        ON origins.diet_id = diets.id) 
                ON products.origin_id = origins.id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  (product_aliases 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (users as users1
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN  profiles as profiles1 ON profiles1.user_id = users1.id
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN  user_options as user_options1 ON user_options1.user_id = users1.id 
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN  avatars as avatars1 ON avatars1.user_id = users1.id
                        ) 
                        ON  product_aliases.user_id =users1.id
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (users as users2
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN  profiles as profiles2 ON profiles2.user_id = users2.id
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN  user_options as user_options2 ON user_options2.user_id = users2.id
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN  avatars as avatars2 ON avatars2.user_id = users2.id 
                        )  
                        ON  product_aliases.edit_user_id = users2.id)
                ON product_aliases.product_id = products.id
```

.....

For example I want to apply limit 1 in the left outer join in origins after  `ON 'products.origin_id'='origins.id'` is possible? How can I do this?
I have tried to put after the on condition limit 1 but give me an error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because this doesn't answer your question at all but rather helps you remove the syntax error. The reason why you are getting that is because the tableName and columnName were enclosed with single quotes when it should be backticks. Ex, `'origin_aliases.origin_id' = 'origins.id'`, the server is comparing for the string `origin_aliases.origin_id` and not on columnName `origin_id` at table `origin_aliases` against column `id` on table `origins`.

Comment: yes but retrieve the same error, if I drop limit from the query there isn't error

Comment: what's the new full error message?

Comment: no new error if I remove limit

Comment: I tried to format the query in your question to make it easier to read, but it is incomplete and seems to have many defects.  Please post a working query and you will get better help.

Comment: sorry the query is very long I have take a part of it. I have put ... to tell that the query isn't finish sorry mine error @BobDuell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your example is full or errors. Your derived tables do not have `SELECT` clauses, you have quoted the table and column references, and it's not clear if names like **origins** and **origin_aliases** are tables or aliases.  Those are your syntax errors.

Once you correct those, you can add the `LIMIT` expression to the entire query or to any of the derived tables.  Here is my best guess:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
   select *
   from   origins 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN origin_aliases 
   ON     origin_aliases.origin_id = origins.id 
      AND origin_aliases.language = '$lang' 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
      select *
      from   diets 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN  diet_aliases 
      ON     diet_aliases.diet_id = diets.id 
         AND diet_aliases.language = '$lang'
      ) d
   ON origins.diet_id=d.id

   LIMIT 1
   ) a
ON products.origin_id=a.id
```

I choose to use two table aliases (**a** and **b**).  And I'm assuming that **origins**, **origin_aliases**, and **diets** are tables.  Note you should not use `SELECT *`; provide the column names you want from each derived table as well as in your main `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIMIT` in a `JOIN` by using a sub-query:

```
... LEFT JOIN (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table LIMIT 2) ON ...
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, don't use single quotes around column names that contain a table.

Comment: Can you apply to my example please? because I have en error again, for example the first left outer join with origins must have limit 1

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: try thinking for yourself some time.